# YUI treeview control not rendering "+" and "-" icons in IE on some machines

Tags: internet-explorer, treeview, yui, gif

We have been using YUI for a long time in out web application and we've just starting having some users report that the "+" and "-" icons are not visible. We can recreate this on only one of our machines.

We are using YUI 2.5.2 and yes I know it's obsolete, we are planning to replace it, but for now I need to know the cause.

The public sample for YUI 2.9.0 presents the same issue:
http://yui.github.io/yui2/docs/yui_2.9.0_full/examples/treeview/default_tree.html

It uses a large GIF (18 x 8800 pixels) and this image won't render in IE on the problem machines if we try to load it directly with the browser.

The GIF Works fine in Chrome on the problem machines.

The GIF fails for all users of the problem machines if we create different logon profiles.

The GIF fails in IE11 and earlier versions of IE on the problem machines.

No error messages raised.

We tried converting the GIF to PNG, same problem. We loaded it in Paint and saved it as a PNG again (without transparency) and it started rendering fine.

We suspect an issue with transparency, but mysteriously only on some machines. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure the GIF does not render when opening directly in browser? In IE11 if you open http://yui.yahooapis.com/2.9.0/build/treeview/assets/skins/sam/treeview-sprite.gif it seems like a blank page, but in reality it's just zoomed to fit the window, thus making the graphics so small that it all looks empty. If you zoom in using ``ctrl +``, you start seeing it.

Comment: Several of us have seen the behaviour you mention, it renders but just barely visible. The suspect systems actually totally fail to render the GIF in IE. The plot thickens! Today my laptop, when using the integrated display, exhibited the same problem, the first time I've seen it with my own eyes. I'll test again tomorrow with external monitors as I normally use the machine.

Comment: Had you tried to redimension the GIF for something like 32x32 or even 64x64 and change it from GIF to BMP or TIF? The problem may be related to GIF with 8888 pixels width.

Comment: @David BS - I suspect you may be right that the dimensions are causing the issue, but the GIF is an integral part of the YUI treeview. We don't have the time or budget to re-write bits of an old library to get around a problem apparent for only some users, and only in Internet Explorer. If there is a simple fix, then I'll take it. Otherwise this issue is going to have to wait until we replace the YUI treeview.

Comment: I've done more testing today - when booting with external monitors and docking station, the GIF renders fine. When using the laptop integrated display, the GIF does not render. I suspect some sort of display driver compatibility issue. Given that Chrome doesn't have the problem, I hope it's possible that it could be dealt with as an MS IE bugfix.

Comment: Sorry for not helped you as I had supposed could do @Michael12345. Good luck.

Comment: @Michael12345 Random idea - what if you added more width to the GIF? Maybe it has something to do with the unusual proportions. So, change the GIF from 18x8800px to 2000x8800 adding the width to the right. Then it won't break the existing view. Keep the transparency. Will it change the behavior? It's a misfortune I cannot reproduce it. It sure is interesting.